# 3rd party Javascript and CSS files in Webpack. Strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I am using the MERN stack. I had to use a 3rd party html admin template which has a lot of standard js and css files (jquery, bootstrap, datatables etc.). To integrate it with react, I created a "public" folder in the root directory of my project. I then configured Express to serve this folder as a static folder and placed the required css and html files inside this folder. To use them, I added the css in the head section of the index.html file and the js in the end of the body. It works when I run the server in development mode and there are no issues. When I run it in production mode, somehow the layout gets messed up. If I refresh it with CTRL + F5 it gets fixed but when I navigate to a new page it gets ruined again and I have to CTRL + F5 it again to display properly.

This is my webpack.config.dev.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
var postcssFocus = require('postcss-focus');
var postcssReporter = require('postcss-reporter');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: {
    app: [
      'eventsource-polyfill',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './client/index.js',
    ],
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      'client',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx*$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.+\.config.js/],
        loader: 'babel',
      }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: 'vendor.js',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        CLIENT: JSON.stringify(true),
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }
    }),
  ],

  postcss: () => [
    postcssFocus(),
    cssnext({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE > 10'],
    }),
    postcssReporter({
      clearMessages: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

This is my webpack.config.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
var ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
var postcssFocus = require('postcss-focus');
var postcssReporter = require('postcss-reporter');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'hidden-source-map',

  entry: {
    app: [
      './client/index.js',
    ],
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/client/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      'client',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?localIdentName=[hash:base64]&modules&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader'),
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx*$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
      }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: 'vendor.js',
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.[chunkhash].css', { allChunks: true }),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      basePath: '/',
    }),
    new ChunkManifestPlugin({
      filename: "chunk-manifest.json",
      manifestVariable: "webpackManifest",
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false,
      }
    }),
  ],

  postcss: () => [
    postcssFocus(),
    cssnext({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE > 10'],
    }),
    cssnano({
      autoprefixer: false
    }),
    postcssReporter({
      clearMessages: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8080 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-test node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony-proxies node_modules/.bin/ava",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "cover": "nyc npm run test",
    "check-coverage": "nyc check-coverage --statements 100 --branches 100 --functions 100 --lines 100",
    "start": "cross-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
    "bs": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build:server && npm run start:prod",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.server.js",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "slate": "rimraf node_modules && npm install",
    "lint": "eslint client server"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint",
    "test"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter#readme",
  "author": "Prashant Abhishek <prashant.abhishek7g@gmail.com>, Mayank Chandola <imayankchd@gmail.com>, Sandeep Panda <sandeep@hashnode.com>, Syed Fazle Rahman <fazle@hashnode.com>, Alkshendra Maurya <alkshendra@hashnode.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.8",
    "cuid": "^1.3.8",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "intl": "^1.2.4",
    "intl-locales-supported": "^1.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "limax": "^1.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.20",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-contexify": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-helmet": "^3.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.1.2",
    "react-notify-toast": "^0.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-toastify": "^4.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^0.15.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-webpack-loaders": "^0.7.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-native-modules": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin": "0.1.0",
    "coveralls": "^2.11.9",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^2.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-ava": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "jsdom": "^9.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mock-css-modules": "^1.0.0",
    "mockgoose": "^6.0.3",
    "nock": "^8.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "nyc": "^6.4.4",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.6.0",
    "postcss-focus": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "postcss-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "pre-commit": "^1.1.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "redux-ava": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "supertest": "^1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.8",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "ava": {
    "files": [
      "client/**/*.spec.js",
      "server/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "source": [
      "client/**/*.js",
      "server/**/*.js"
    ],
    "failFast": true,
    "babel": "inherit",
    "require": [
      "./server/util/setup-test-env.js"
    ]
  },
  "nyc": {
    "include": [
      "client/**/*.js",
      "server/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.spec.js",
      "client/reducers.js",
      "client/store.js",
      "client/routes.js",
      "server/util/setup-test-env.js",
      "server/util/test-helpers.js",
      "server/config.js",
      "server/dummyData.js"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "html"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can this be fixed?

EDIT: It seems that the page sometimes loads correctly even without CTRL + F5 refresh. My gut tells me the issue lies with the order that the JS files are loaded. Any tips on how to keep the loading order the same in dev and prod?

Comment: Have you tried it in incognito mode?

Comment: @TamasSzoke Yes. Same behaviour. When I refresh with CTRL + F5, it loads ok. Otherwise, layout gets messed up.

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: @ThiagoLoddi I have one live example but I have run the server in development mode. I can show it to you in private. What kind of information would you need from a live example? I can run it and send you what you need.

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` to see the library versions you're using

Comment: check and debug which ones are not loading when you moove from a page to another, then check which trigger they have. We had a similar issue and the boy that was doing it had a "document ready like" trigger but then some lib performed a prevent default when changing from one internal to another.

Answer (score 0):

In case of  **webpack.config.prod.js** If you see this part of code

```
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?localIdentName=[hash:base64]&modules&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader'),    42.         loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',}
```

Just remove **ExtractTextPlugin.extract** and modify this part of code to

```
'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader'
```

Comment: Same behaviour. I am almost sure the issue lies with the JS files not the CSS ones.

Comment: Yes I have. Didn't fix it. Check the original question, I edited it.

Comment: You can use head.js (http://headjs.com/) .if you want to maintain order of script loading.